# Binary tree lookup

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am building a binary tree in C++ using recursion and I can't figure out why I can't return an Item, it's probably a simple thing I'm over looking but I've been looking at it so long I can't figure it out.

```
BST::Item * BST::lookup(Key k)
{
    return(lookupRec(k, root));
}

BST::Item * BST::lookupRec(Key k, Node* n)
{
    if (k == n->key)
    {
        return n->item; //problem is here
    }
    else if (k > n->key)
    {
        lookupRec(k, n->rightChild);
    }
    else if (k < n->key)
    {
        lookupRec(k, n->leftChild);
    }
    else
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

to add some context Item is `using Item = std::string;` so I call the lookup with a key and it calls the worker function and should return the item when the key and root key match, but it won't return the n->item because it says there is no suitable conversion from BST::Item to BST::Item*

any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Well the error is clear, isn't it? `n->item` holds a `std::string` and you are trying to return a pointer to a `std::string`. (On that note, *why* do you want to return a pointer to the `std::string`? Why not return a reference to it?)

Comment: Compile your program with all warnings enabled. And treat them as errors. How many branches are there in the lookup function? How many of them end in a return statement?

Answer (score 1):

Where you call `lookupRec()` recursively, you should also return, otherwise, you will return nothing from that function instance: `return lookupRec(k, n->rightChild);`

And as @UnholySheep already mentioned: return the right type, as the compiler tells you: `return &(n->item);`